# Docker - Downloaded war not found

Tags: linux, docker

I am trying to download a war file from Nexus repo using the command RUN CURL  in docker file. On building the docker file i can see that a 54 MB war is getting downloaded but not able to find it anywhere.

Docker image size is 342 MB without the curl command and 394 MB with CURL command.

Where is the war file? Is it the part of the image that is being created?

I'm very new to docker so trying to understand what's going on

Comment: Can you share your `Dockerfile` here ? I will help you

Comment: FROM tomcat:latest
MAINTAINER ManasChhabra

RUN curl -X GET -o myApp.war -L "https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/appdev/sample/sample.war"

Answer (score 0):

You have to create `Dockerfile` like this.

```
FROM tomcat:latest 
MAINTAINER ManasChhabra 
RUN \
mkdir -p /opt/war
RUN \
cd /opt/war/ ; \
curl -X GET -o myApp.war -L "tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/appdev/sample/sample.war&q‌​uot
```

Now your war file will be downloaded in `/opt/war/` directory.

hope this will help you!

Thank you!